# Как в 1С с помощью регистра сведении достать номер документа?

Tags: 1с

Задача такая: Есть `РегистрСведении-ДополнительныеСведении`, есть `Документ-ИнвентаризацияОС`.

В стандартном реквизите документа есть `Номер`.

У `РегистрСведении-ДополнительныеСведении` и `Документ-ИнвентаризацияОС` общее это название основного средства (проблема в том, что у документа название основного средства находится в табличной части).

Нужно получить `номер документа` по данным из `РегистраСведений`. Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Твоё решение то где ? Что не получилось ?

Comment: @santavital Примерно вот так:

`Запрос = Новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст =
    "Выбрать
|Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.ОсновноеСредство,
|РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Объект.Наименование
    |Из Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС 
 |ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения
    |ПО Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Объект.Наименование 
 | ГДЕ РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Значение=&Значение";`

Общее между двумя таблицами это название ОС. Получится ли с помощью данного регистра достать номер документа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой задаче как я понимаю, необходимо знать следующую деталь: при обращении к табличной части можно получить ссылку на документ `Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.Ссылка` и далее получить доступ ко всем реквизитам документа `Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.Ссылка.Номер`

Запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ // <- оставляем только уникальные значения, иначе задвоятся
Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.ОсновноеСредство КАК ОсновноеСредство
ИЗ
   Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС
ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения ПО 
    (Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС.ОсновноеСредство = 
    РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Объект)  // .Наименование <- это зачем ?
  И РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Свойство.Наименование = &Свойство
  И РегистрСведений.ДополнительныеСведения.Значение = &Значение
```

В итоге получим Номер документа, ОсновноеСредство (без задвоений) для всех Основных средств у которых `&Свойство = &Значение` (`&Свойство` - это строковое наименование свойства, `&Значение` - должно быть того же типа строка/число и т.п.)